# How to fix problem with this certificate in open edx

Tags: openedx

I am setting up the certificate in the open edX. When I preview certificate then we are getting error in LMS.

To resolve the problem, your partner manager should verify that the following information is correct.

The institution's logo.

The institution that is linked to the course.

The course information in the Course Administration tool.

If all of the information is correct and the problem persists, contact technical support.

My error log /edx/var/log/lms/edx.log

```
Apr 26 14:47:13 ubuntu [service_variant=lms][util.views][env:sandbox] ERROR [ubuntu  17907] [views.py:154] - Error in django view.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/djangoapps/util/views.py", line 145, in inner
    return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/lms/djangoapps/certificates/views/webview.py", line 614, in render_html_view
    return _render_valid_certificate(request, context, custom_template)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/lms/djangoapps/certificates/views/webview.py", line 680, in _render_valid_certificate
    return render_to_response("certificates/valid.html", context)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/djangoapps/edxmako/shortcuts.py", line 169, in render_to_response
    return HttpResponse(render_to_string(template_name, dictionary, namespace, request), **kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/djangoapps/edxmako/shortcuts.py", line 159, in render_to_string
    return template.render(dictionary, request)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/djangoapps/edxmako/template.py", line 59, in render
    return self.mako_template.render_unicode(**context_dictionary)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mako/template.py", line 454, in render_unicode
    as_unicode=True)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 829, in _render
    **_kwargs_for_callable(callable_, data))
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 864, in _render_context
    _exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 890, in _exec_template
    callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/mako_lms/39ae603da0f29d1cb182b9ecdbe643a6/certificates/accomplishment-base.html.py", line 79, in render_body
    runtime._include_file(context, u'_accomplishment-footer.html', _template_uri)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 752, in _include_file
    callable_(ctx, **_kwargs_for_include(callable_, context._data, **kwargs))
  File "/tmp/mako_lms/39ae603da0f29d1cb182b9ecdbe643a6/certificates/_accomplishment-footer.html.py", line 29, in render_body
    __M_writer(filters.html_escape(filters.decode.utf8(company_tos_url)))
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mako/filters.py", line 78, in decode
    return decode(str(x))
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mako/runtime.py", line 226, in __str__
    raise NameError("Undefined")
NameError: Undefined
```

Comment: Open edx's slack channel might help, community is not quite active here in SO.

Answer (score 5):

This issue is happening because you haven't enabled the HTML view configuration.

1. Go to the admin page
   http://localhost/admin/certificates/certificatehtmlviewconfiguration/.
2. Click on the Add certificate html view configuration.
3. Then you will need to select the Enabled checkbox.